# I need to convert date (25/01/2019) to Jan'19 format in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert the contents of a `DATE` colum and store it in another column.

### Example

(25/01/2019) to Jan'19.

Comment: `DATE` doesn't have a format, it stored as a binary data, unless you're storing it as formatted string, which is bad idea. So what's the data type of your column/variable? and what are you really trying to do? Did you search for `FORMAT()` or `CONVERT()` before asking?

Comment: i have a Date Column (data type is Date), and i want to convert date into string in saprate column( for example i have a date 01/01/2019 in one column i want to update another column as Jan'19

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 7)`

Comment: @DilipKumar No, you don't. This is surely an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Formatting of dates (and numbers) should be done in the presentation layer, not the database.

Answer (score 0):

This following option is not a good one considering performance but you can get your desired result-

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(CAST(FORMAT(CONVERT(DAte,'25/01/2019',103), 'MMM-yy') AS VARCHAR),'-','''')
```

Comment: It's not good just for performance? Can we cast the results to a `DATE` again? How do we know the day? BTW, always specify the length of a N/VARCHAR(n)

Comment: OP just need the Month and Year as formatted 'Jan'19 '. Why day is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use of **`FORMAT`** is to get value is desired format.
if you have hardcode date you can use this one :

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(FORMAT(CONVERT(Date,'25/01/2019',103), 'MMM-yy'),'-','''')
```

if you have column in database then you can use :

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(DateColumnHere, 'MMM-yy') ,'-','''')
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

A date type column has no format but we can change the display format by converting it to a string. In your case, `[myDate]` should be a string type column such as `varchar`, and we'll cast it to `date` before converting the display format. So consider :

```
with tab([myDate]) as
(
 select '25/01/2019'
)
select convert(varchar, 
               cast(concat(substring(myDate,7,4),'-',
                           substring(myDate,4,2),'-',
                           substring(myDate,1,2)) as date) ,6)
    as [myDate]
  from tab;

  myDate
  ---------
  25 Jan 19
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=634a9e3318245149f76a9e1ad398b90a)</kbd>